# Billing Tier is out of expected range

Tags: google-bigquery

While observing the totalBytesBilled and billingTier fields to see which of our queries will be billed at a higher tier, among expected 1,2 and 3 as a values for billingTier - I noticed value 4 for some of queries.

In Query pricing document there are only 3 mentioned: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand

What tier is billingTier=4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being, `billingTier` can be arbitrarily high in order to give you a sense of where your query will land. When the High Compute tiers go live, any tier above 3 will result in a `resourcesExceeded` error unless you make special arrangements with BigQuery (contact support).

There are some corner cases where a poorly-partitioned table (our fault) may lead to an artificially high billing tier. We're working on finding and eliminating these corner cases, so please check back in a little bit.